# Pasar props con styled-components React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

me encuentro con el siguiente problema, le quiero pasar por props a un styled-component(span) para asignarle ese valor a la propiedad "content" en el before del dicho elemento :

```
const IconsWrapper = styled.span`
position:relative;
:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:${props => props.description};
    
}

svg{
        color:var(--darkest-gray);
        font-size:40px;
        transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
        :hover{
            color:var(--orange)
        }
    }
```

`

```
</TechnologiesHeader>

            <TechnologiesIcons>
                {icons.map((icon) => {
                    return(
                        <IconsWrapper description = {icon.description}>
                            {icon.icon}
                        </IconsWrapper>
                    )
                })
                }
            </TechnologiesIcons>
            
        </TechnologiesContainer>
```

Una cosa así seria, pero no esta terminado porque no me funciona. No estoy seguro si esto se puede hacer o que parte estoy haciendo mal. Agradecería una ayuda. Muchas gracias

Comment: Que es lo que no funciona? en principio no veo ningún error... Ya re-verificaste que inspeccionando el <before> del elemento no tenga esas propiedades?

Comment: Si inspecciono el elemento así como esta no me aparece el before en el navegador, pero si a content le pongo algo estático como por ejemplo "hola" si aparece en el navegador.. no tengo idea que puede ser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al inspeccionar en Chrome y en Edge el content aparece sin comillas, si le agrego comillas se muestra sin problemas:

```
content: "${ props  =>   props.description}"
```

así debería funcionar

Comment: Ya lo habia podido resolver, y fue asi como lo hiciste. Gracias igual, le puede servir a otra persona. Un saludo